# Trying to test vue component that use mapState from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, sinon

Currently trying to test a vue component that is using the vuex ...mapState method but just by bringing it into the component fails my tests.

This is the current error i'm getting:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Object$defineProperty from "../../core-js/object/define-property";
```

This is my component I'm trying to test.

```
SimpleComponent.vue


<template>
  <h1> Hello!!!</h1>
</template>

<script>
import mapState from 'vuex';
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(["users"])
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This is my store but simplified for testing purposes.

```
store.js


import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
const fb = require("./firebaseConfig.js");

Vue.use(Vuex);

fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
      store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)

      // realtime updates from our posts collection
      fb.usersCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          let userArray = []

          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              let user = doc.data()
              user.id = doc.id
              userArray.push(user)
          })

          store.commit('setUsers', userArray)
      })
  }
})

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users:[], 
  },
  actions: {
    clearData({ commit }) {
      commit('setUsers', null);
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, val){
      state.users = val
    }, 
  },
});
```

And here is my test

```
SimpleComponentTest.spec.js

import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import SimpleStore from '../../src/components/SimpleComponent.vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

const sinon = require('sinon');
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe('SimpleComponent.vue', () => {
    it('Is Vue Instance', () => {
        const wp = shallowMount(SimpleComponent, { computed: { users: () => 'someValue' }, localVue });
        expect(wp.isVueInstance()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Im using Jest with Sinon for testing. I am a little confused on the proper way to set up the store in my test but this is one way I found when looking online.

The code base is a little bigger than what I am showing you but that is because after running into errors for hours I figured I needed the simplest piece of code to test that uses the ...mapState method and build it back up from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Goal: To get a simple test to pass that tests a component that uses ...mapState([]) from vuex

Comment: Replace `import mapState from 'vuex';` by `import {mapState} from 'vuex';`. mapState is a property of the default export of Vuex, so you need to destructure it.

Comment: @seblor Just updated the code with that change. Test still fails but thats good to know I was doing wrong.